# Detecting mouse button down & up events on the system menu of form

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

How do I detect left mouse button down and up events on the 'Close' option of the system menu that appears when the mouse is clicked on the top left corner of a form?

Comment: Do you mean "How to implement MouseDown event for a [MenuItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menuitem_events(v=vs.110).aspx)?"

Comment: Yes, but that's only for the 'Close' option of the system menu that appears when you click the top left corner of the title bar of a form.

Comment: Ok. Did you check below answer? Why does it NOT work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You don't, there is the [Form.Closing event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the [Form.Closed event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on your form